# Php pdo_dblib - cannot find/unable to load freetds

Tags: php, rhel6, pdo, sybase, freetds

Self-hosted box,
RHEL 6
PHP 5.3.3

PDO installed
freetds installed
pdo_dblib - so far no luck installing

My goal is to use PDO with sybase.  Attempting to install pdo_dblib from the appropriate version php source code.  I have tried a variety of methods and searched quite a bit for help on this topic, but have yet to be successful.

## Method 1

### Install freetds

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ su root
Password: 
$ make install
```

This is successful

### Install pdo_dblib

inside the /ext/pdo_dblib folder:

```
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make test
```

Error output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so' - /home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so' - /home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so' - /home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so' - /home/sybase/Install_items/php_533_src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_dblib/modules/pdo_dblib.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
```

That doesn't look good...I researched this and found an interesting hack for this [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=697015).  But changing pdo.ini to pdo_0.ini was not the solution, as I still got the same errors on make test.

```
$ su
$ make install
```

Output:

```
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib64/php/modules/
```

That seems strange...and no, it doesn't actually install (not showing up on phpinfo after apache restart).

## Method 2

### Install freetds

following the instructions exactly, i add the prefix

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds
$ make
$ su root
Password: 
$ make install
```

This is successful

### Install pdo_dblib

inside the /ext/pdo_dblib folder:

```
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-sybase=/usr/local/freetds
```

This produces the following error at the bottom of the output

```
...
checking for PDO_DBLIB support via FreeTDS... yes, shared
configure: error: Cannot find FreeTDS in known installation directories
```

## Method 3

freetds ./configure variation (including or not include the --prefix...) did not change the result of this so I'll skip it.

### Install pdo_dblib pecl extension

following the method specified [here](http://www.richardhyland.com/diary/2009/02/25/two-days-with-pdo-and-my-lack-of-faith-in-the-php-extension-developers/).

```
pecl download pdo_dblib
tar -xzvf PDO_DBLIB-1.0.tgz
```

Removed the line,

```
<dep type=”ext” rel=”ge” version=”1.0″>pdo</dep>
```

Saved the package.xml file, and moved it in to the PDO_DBLIB directory.

```
mv package.xml ./PDO_DBLIB-1.0
```

Navigated to the PDO_DBLIB directory, then installed the package from the
directory.

```
cd ./PDO_DBLIB-1.0
pecl install package.xml
```

But, this command gives me the following error output, same as **Method 2**.

```
checking for PDO_DBLIB support via FreeTDS... yes, shared
configure: error: Cannot find FreeTDS in known installation directories
ERROR: `/home/sybase/Install_items/pecl_pdo_dblib/PDO_DBLIB-1.0/configure' failed
```

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem when trying to install PDO_INFORMIX on a CentOS 6.3 with PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: I have tried also renaming pdo.ini to 0_pdo.ini but the problem persists: `pdo_informix.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: I have same issue to use FreeTDS with pdo_dblib, you got success here?

Answer (score 1):

After method 1, check your ini files and be sure that the pdo.so and pdo_dblib.so files are configured to be loaded.  You can do this from the command line with a php -i and look for the "Loaded Configuration File" as well as "Additional .ini files parsed".

Among those files, ensure that extendion=pdo.so is loaded (possibly/probably before your pdo_dblib.so is loaded).  If you want to maintain separate .ini files you can control the load order by how a straight `ls -al` orders the files.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to method one and rebuild freetds with

```
./configure --enable-msdblib
```

and possibly

```
--enable-sybase-compat
```

If it still fails, post the output of ldd against any .so that fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works nowadays:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm && \
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm && \
yum update -y && yum install --enablerepo=remi -y \
    php-cli \
    php-fpm \
    php-mssql
```

You can verify PDO DBLIB installed by sifting the output of the following command:

```
php -i
```